# Ruby on Rails - Friendly-ID - Id is processed as slug on destroy method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, destroy, friendly-id

everything is working fine apart from the destroy method for my user model. I'm FAIRLY sure now that it has something to do with the Friendly_ID gem.

If I require a password then i get an error of `invalid password`.
If I don't require a password then the `User` 'apparently' deletes, but it doesn't. (my `flash[:success]` shows with the corresponding redirect)

Server logs:

```
Processing by UsersController#destroy as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"SkfqooVdKgfsgoL78+yZDxSYoTJNqzUfmyWfGTv8LOxSEObnaKEhip837yrEK5bHVO0HJ/6dmKHqUZmiiWoqDg==", "user"=>{"current_password"=>"[FILTERED]"}, "commit"=>"Delete", "locale"=>"en", "id"=>"e2dc"}
```

Here the ID is shown as "e2dc" instead of the real ID of 20. (e2dc is the username and slug of this current user)

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  extend FriendlyId
  friendly_id :username, use: [:slugged, :finders]
end

class UsersController < ApplicationController

  def destroy
    @user = current_user
    @user.id = params[:user_id]
    if @user.destroy_with_password(user_params)
        redirect_to feedbacks_url, notice: "User deleted."
    else
      render "account"
      flash.now[:notice] = @user.errors.full_messages
    end
  end
end

<%= simple_form_for(@user, :method => :delete) do |f| %>
  <%= f.input :current_password, autocomplete: "off", required: true %>
  <%= f.button :submit, "Delete" %>
<% end %>
```

---

I have tried using `User.friendly.find` without any luck. EVERYTHING else works in my project.

Thanks for any advice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following:

```
def destroy
  @user = User.find(params[:id])

  if @user.destroy_with_password(params[:user][:current_password])
    redirect_to feedbacks_url, notice: "User deleted."
  else
    flash.now[:notice] = @user.errors.full_messages
    render "account"  
  end
end
```

Comment: This works perfectly, although I don't understand why. With every other method in my controller, (I even have an update method in the same controller that users `update_with_password(user_params)` I can user `@user = current_user` or `find.(params[:id])`. Thank you anyway!!